Shouldn't questions regarding Italian culture and history be on topic?
Constato che il numero delle domande è estremamente ridotto, e tende a diminuire nonostante si sia passati in fase pubblica, nonché considerato che al netto delle  mie domande il numero delle stesse tende paurosamente a zero, dovremmo considerare, onde preservare il futuro del sito dal rischio di chiusura, di estenderne le finalità alla scrittura, alla storia e alla cultura —italiana, ovviamente—, di cui la lingua è parte?
Scusate se sembro pessimista, ma dubito che la lingua italiana possa mai avere un interesse internazionale tale da assicurare a IL un numero quotidiano di domande che sia sufficiente a giustificarne l'esistenza su SE.
Peraltro, è ormai chiarissimo che i madrelingua tendono a non chiedere alcunché, e questo mi sembra che accada anche su altri siti simili e in primis su ELU.
Chi non crede che sia così, rifletta.

Beh, qui parliamo della lingua, domande su di essa in relazione e cultura erano ciò che proponevo in http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/questions/62/do-we-have-linguists-and-or-people-with-general-background-but-interested-in-lan

@martina, sí, ma molti hanno ritenuto che fossero too broad, però. Qui, invece, vorrei si capisse che non mi riferisco a too broad questions, but to questions which fit the SE format, anyway.

I agree up to a certain extent, that is, the questions have to concern the Italian language.
It's clear that we welcome questions related to the history, the sociology of the language, apart from those on grammar, lexicon, syntax and so on.
But this is a site for the Italian language, not Italy or whatever as a whole!
As for the native speakers asking few questions, just a few days have passed since the public beta has started, be positive!

martina, but Spanish Language has 0.9 visit/day ratio, for example. So, how do you think that Italian Langauge can do better if its speakers are not more than 80,000,000 of persons while Spanish Language has 1,000,000,000 of speakers?

@KyriakosKyritsis I don't see how that is really relevant. What about non-native speakers? They are needed as well to ask questions. :P Maybe even more!

I believe that we should not modify or unduly enlarge the scope of the site. Should really the traffic and number of question be insufficient, then the site will deserve to be closed. So be it.

... e solo perche' nel titolo c'e' scritto 'Language'? Otto letterine che possono essere cambiate in 'Culture' in un attimo. Cio' che conta e' l'indirizzo internet dove compare solo 'italian', no?

If the site were "Italian Culture" the thing would be different; since the site's title is "Italian Language," it's obvious that you cannot ask sociology questions that are not in someway related with language.

@KyriakosKyritsis: This is a site about Italian language (its title is due to its subject, not the other way around); people has followed and committed to it as such. Perhaps someone wouldn't have if it were about something else. In my opinion, we should keep it as it is; if it were to fail, you or someone else will be quite free to propose a new one with a broader scope (language, history, art, you name it).
